# How to pass client-JS variable to Node-JS server-side variable?

Tags: node.js

This is my client.js

```
navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
function successCallback (stream) { //I want to pass the stream variable to server-side NodeJS
   var video = document.querySelector('video');
   video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
   video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
      // Do something with the video here.
   };
}
//...
```

This is my server.js

```
var PitchDetect = require('pitch-detect'),
    pitchDetect = new PitchDetect(stream); // I want to get the stream variable from client.js

pitchDetect.getPitch();
```

How to tell nodeJS that in server.js file, the `stream` variable is the same as `stream` variable from client.js ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: You can't. They are different programs (probably) running on different computers. They don't share variables.

Comment: Yes, but to achieve what I want, What must I do ? An http request ?